# Pass Columns of 2 D array as a parameter in Java

Tags: java, arrays, row

I want to only pass columns of a 2 d array in a method call. I know how to pass 2 d row by row and that is

`Check(a[i],9);` taken in mind that a is defined as a 2 d array.

However I don't know how to do that row by row... not when doing this gives error

```
 Check(a[i][],9);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access a 'column' in a 2d array in this way, at least not in Java. You would need to manually iterate the rows and select the column value you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this without explicitly creating an array and copying from your original matrix element by element.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand your question correctly, but i think you are missing a second loop.

```
for( int i = 0; i < a.length; i++ )
{
   for( int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++ )
   {
      cellAtRowIColumnJ(a[i][j], 9) //what is the 9 for?
   } 
}
```

you might also want this (not sure) dunno if this compiles, the idea is to copy the column values to a new array and pass that

```
int[] cols = new int[a.length];
for( int i = 0; i < a.length; i++ )
{
   cols[i] = a[i][9];
}
callWithColumns(cols);
```

Answer (score 1):

A 2d array is not a matrix.  It behaves more like an array of arrays.

```
int a[][];
for (int b[] : a)
    for (int c : b)
        System.out.print(c);
```

What you appear to be looking for is an array made of the first element of each of the inner arrays, which cannot be accessed automatically.  You would need to make a new array.

```
int temp[] = new int[a.length];
for (int x = 0; x < temp.length; x++)
    temp[x] = a[x][0];
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you would need to create that array like so and then pass it:

```
int column = 0; // column you want to get
int[] col = new int[a.length];
for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    col[i] = a[i][column];
}

// col is now what you want to pass.
Check(col, 9);
```